# Image change when toggle on/off

Tags: jquery, html, css

My toggle is opening a menu and inside that menu I have two images. I want to change toggle between the 2 images, but couldn't do it properly.

*Jquery*

```
$(function(){
   $(".accordion dt").click(function(){
        $(this).next("dd").slideToggle();
        $(this).next("dd").siblings("dd").slideUp();
        $(this).toggleClass("open");    
        $(this).siblings("dt").removeClass("open");
    });          
});
```

*HTML*

```
<dl class="accordion">
<dt>
    <span class="image"><img src="img/question-off.png" class="size click-former"><img src="img/question-on.png" class="click1 size"></span>
    <span class="text">Some Text Here</span>
    <span class="image2"><img src="img/open-blue-big.png" class="size-btn"></span>
</dt>
</dl>
```

and in Css I hiding toggle on img.

```
.click1 {
    display: none;
}
```

but a bit confused how to change it, on or off.

### Update

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r0jn8mve/13/)

in the fiddle there two image 100x50 and 100x100 when my toggle on or off(background color changing) also want to change image too.

Comment: can you please make a fiddle

Comment: add code on `fiddle` and provide link

Comment: can you explain what it means to change image(if off as i understand `dt` not shown so what you want to change)

Comment: I updated question, add some explanation and fiddle @NegiRox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use only **one** image and change the `src` in function `$(".size").attr('src','https://via.placeholder.com/100x50')`:

[See fiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/r0jn8mve/17/)

```js
    $(function(){
     
     $(".accordion dt").click(function(){
      $(this).next("dd").slideToggle();
      $(this).next("dd").siblings("dd").slideUp();
      $(this).toggleClass("open"); 
      $(this).siblings("dt").removeClass("open");
        $('.accordion > dt *:not(.open) .size').attr('src','https://via.placeholder.com/100x50');
        if($('.open .size').attr('src')=='https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oh6WR.png')
           $(".open .size").attr('src','https://via.placeholder.com/100x50');
        else
           $(".open .size").attr('src','https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oh6WR.png');
           
       });

      
      });
```

```css
  dd {
     margin: 0;
    }

    dl.accordion {
     font-family: Helvetica Neue; 
     width:100%;
     font-size:16px;
    }

    dl.accordion dt {
        border-bottom:1px solid #9ED6E2; 
        height:auto; 
        text-indent:10px; 
        line-height:20px; 
        color:#333; 
        font-weight:medium; 
        cursor:pointer;
    }



    dl.accordion dt.open {
        background-color: #9ED6E2;
        color: white;
    }

    img{
      width:100px;
      height:100px;
    }

    dl.accordion dd { 
     background:#FFF; 
     padding:10px;
     line-height:1.5; 
     display:none;
    }

    dl.accordion dd.text {
     padding-left: 10px;
    }

    dt, dd {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }

    dt > span {
     padding-top: 10px;
        display: block;
    }

    dt > span.text { 
     flex-grow: 1;

    }

    dt > span.image2 {
     padding-right: 10px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <dl class="accordion">
    <dt>
     <span class="image">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x50" class="size">
     </span>
     <span class="text">マンションを購入しようとした時に、何から始めたらよいのでしょうか?</span>
    <span class="image2"><img src="img/open-blue-big.png" class="size-btn"></span>
    </dt>
    <dt>
     <span class="image">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x50" class="size">
     </span>
     <span class="text">second dt only to example</span>
    <span class="image2"><img src="img/open-blue-big.png" class="size-btn"></span>
    </dt>
    </dl>
```

Comment: actuallt It s works, but I am trying to use it on other dt too. and it changing all at once. I want to change just when I clicked it and when I click it again I want it to return the same. But it doesn't return same.

Comment: to explain it more I took same pic: here the first one it's normal: https://imgur.com/a/LfpgPrm and when I click it it changes unclicked button too:https://imgur.com/a/AcTA7Hv

Comment: thank you, it solved one problem. But when I click other item, first clicked not return first pic. clicked image stays. I am trying to do when click other item, first clicked return first image. I mean I doesn't toggle when I click other item.

Comment: to explain it: https://imgur.com/a/tchYZ1f I click two image, but first clicked one, doesn't return blue again stays with white.

Comment: do you mean when you click on second you want the first be with `https://via.placeholder.com/100x50` image again? what about white/blue??

Comment: yes, that's right!! white, blue is color of my images, don't mind it.

Comment: is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I added id to both images. On your toggle function I'm also toggling both images.

```js
$(function() {

  $(".accordion dt").click(function() {
    $(this).next("dd").slideToggle();
    $(this).next("dd").siblings("dd").slideUp();
    $(this).toggleClass("open");
    $(this).siblings("dt").removeClass("open");
    $("#open-image").toggle();
    $("#close-image").toggle();
  });

});
```

```css
dd {
  margin: 0;
}

dl.accordion {
  font-family: Helvetica Neue;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
}

dl.accordion dt {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #9ED6E2;
  height: auto;
  text-indent: 10px;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #333;
  font-weight: medium;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.click1 {
  display: none;
}

dl.accordion dt.open {
  background-color: #9ED6E2;
  color: white;
}

dl.accordion dd {
  background: #FFF;
  padding: 10px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  display: none;
}

dl.accordion dd.text {
  padding-left: 10px;
}

dt,
dd {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

dt>span {
  padding-top: 10px;
  display: block;
}

dt>span.text {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

dt>span.image2 {
  padding-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<dl class="accordion">
  <dt>
   <span class="image">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x50" id="open-image" class="size">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100"id="close-image" class="click1 size">
    </span>
  <span class="text">マンションを購入しようとした時に、何から始めたらよいのでしょうか?</span>
  <span class="image2"><img src="img/open-blue-big.png" class="size-btn"></span>
 </dt>
</dl>

<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x50">
```